# codeigniter template engine like in Wordpress Or Joomla

Tags: codeigniter, template-engine

Is there a Codeigniter Library or extension which would make possible dynamic templating like in  Wordpress or Joomla. What I mean I would like to point my controller to a view  which is specified by admin from back.

than I was starting to create by myself but till this point without any success

```
controller
--main_conroler
```

here some trying what did not succeed

```
class MainController extends CI_Controller {
    /*  Initiate Site
     */

    private $method;

    private $data;




    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->load->helper('url');

        $this->load->helper('language');

        $this->method = $this->router->fetch_method();

        if ($this->method == "index") {
            $this->data['view'] = 'templates/appStrapp';
        } elseif ($this->method != 'site' && method_exists(__CLASS__, $this->method)) {
            $this->data['view'] = $this->method;
        }

        if (empty($this->data['view'])) {
            show_404();
        }
    }
```

**View**

```
view
--templates
---default
----index.php
```

than here I would like to route my template parts

```
<?php if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

if (file_exists(dirname(__FILE__) . '/tmpl/' . $view . '.php')) {

    include ( dirname(__FILE__) . '/tmpl/header.php');

    include ( dirname(__FILE__) . '/tmpl/navigation.php');

    $this->load->view('site/tmpl/' . $view);

    include ( dirname(__FILE__) . '/tmpl/footer.php');
} else { 
    var_dump('test');
    show_404();
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've used the following for templates in CI and it's a nice setup.

https://github.com/philsturgeon/codeigniter-template

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion I've been taking a look on it seems to be really outdated. I don't know if this would be compatible with codeigniter3